# How can I sign out from NTLM login for php with Apache + mod_authnz_sspi

Tags: php, apache, sspi

I am using Apache + mod_authnz_sspi under Windows 10. I want to sign out a user (end the NTLM session) when it reach a time limit. Then the user need to sign in again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, you need to log out from your windows session (as authentication is delegated to Windows).

If you want a user to be able to log out from your app you should use another SSO mechanism (for example SAML).